# Can iCloud's Documents and Data be configured to sync on a per-app basis?

Tags: ios, mac, icloud

I'm considering buying DayOne, a journaling app for iOS and Mac that syncs through iCloud's Documents and Data feature. I already own the iWork app suite on iOS and Mac, and I do not want to use iCloud syncing for the iWork apps. Is there a way I can turn on the Documents and Data syncing on iCloud for use with DayOne without having the iWork apps sync through iCloud?

edit: Thanks for the iOS portion of the answer, Jonathan. I still would like an explicit answer about the iWork apps on my Mac, though. Has iWork '09 been updated for iCloud? If so, does each app have a setting to turn on/off iCloud storage? I read somewhere that there's a ~/Library/Mobile Documents folder where your files are stored if you are using iCloud, and I want to be sure that I do what is necessary to prevent the iWork apps from doing this once I enable Documents & Settings on my Mac. Please reference the source of your information. I'd rather not have to learn by trial & error. Has anyone already tried this?

edit 2: Sorry I didn't specify earlier, I thought it was an obvious assumption, but I'm using iOS version 5.1 on my iPhone and OS X Lion on my Mac (the latest released versions of both operating systems).

Comment: I amended by answer with more details.

Comment: Updated again with screen shots.  In short, iWork on Mountain Lion (and likely Lion in future) will save to iCloud on a per document basis, as per the example screenshot given for Text Edit in Mountain Lion Developer Preview.  Either way, none of it can possible affect DayOne, or viceversa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable iCloud on iWork by going to the Settings app, and scroll down to the install apps settings, you will find each iWork app has it's own section, Pages, Numbers and Keynote.

In each iWork app's settings there is an option "Use iCloud". Turn this to off, and keep the Documents and Data in the iCloud menu on.

For Mac, the iWork apps do not support iCloud Document Sync. (If you enable sync on iOS, the files created on iOS will download into your library, you can't open them however, and you are unable to upload to iCloud in iWork)

In Mountain Lion they will, but it appears that iCloud Doc sync integration will be at the OS Level, rather than iWork app level. Instead being more like DropBox* where you have an area (I say area, because it's not a folder, but it's quite similar to one) for iCloud.

*Although this area only seems to appear in Open/Save Dialogs, and will only show files that are registered to the App.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, for the iOS portion of the answer. Please see my edit to the original question.

Comment: Sorry completely missed the Mac part (was there ever an iOS part to start with?)

Answer (score 1):

The primary element of syncing is having Data to sync.

If you simply do not chose to store documents in iCloud and instead choose to store them locally on your hard drive in the way you have always previously done, then those files cannot be synchronised by iCloud, even if it remains turned "on" (Where "on" really means "available to use if you want to" rather than "It's on, you're now using it")

DayOne has a similar option, you can choose to use iCloud, or you can choose the old fashioned file/folder method.  The fact that this folder can be in Dropbox and then result in subsequent synchronising is not relevant to the app.

So, in summary, using iCloud requires you to knowingly put your files into the cloud.  Your existing files and indeed file locations will remain unaffected if you continue to use them.

As pointed out in another answer and subsequent edit to the question, the iWork suite '09 for Mac has yet to be updated to use iCloud.  Chances are it will not be, and the OS will simply handle this for all supported applications.  iCloud enabled documents in Mountain Lion simply share the same save dialogue that any normal document has, there is simply a toggle at the top of the dialogue that you can flip to say local or icloud.  As such, you have the choice to save to either/or on a per document basis, and there will be no system wide setting to choose one or the other on the Mac.  This mechanism will likely be brought into Lion when ML is released.

[image]

Regardless of ANY of the above, DayOne app syncing over iCloud has got absolutely no relationship with any other Application, whether is used iCloud or not, and can happily be configured to use iCloud completely independently of your choices for other apps.

Comment: No, I disagree, on iOS if you have iCloud doc sync in iWork enabled, then all documents you create on there will be put on iCloud (automatically), iWork Mac isn't iCloud ready yet so it's not known how that will work (things can change in the DP of Mountain Lion)

Comment: The iWork bit of the question is an aside.  The main question is whether setting iCloud on for one app will take affect in another app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Stuffe. Though hastily typed and a bit off-topic (Mountain Lion isn't in stores yet), it's interesting and educational to see where Apple is going with iCloud in the near future.

Comment: Initial answer from iPhone, typos agogo :)  Veering towards off topic, but given that iWork Mac doesn't support iCloud, any answer referencing it has to by definition be speculative at one level or another.